# How to configure mysql in ejabberd server?

Tags: mysql, yaml, xmpp, ejabberd

I have this config in my `ejabberd.yml` file

```
sql_type: "mysql"
sql_port: "3306"
sql_server: "localhost"
sql_database: "ejabberd" 
sql_username: "root"
sql_password: "root"
```

And in `error.log` file giving me this error

> 2019-08-08 17:33:13.493 [critical] <0.105.0>@ejabberd_app:start:71
>   Failed to start ejabberd application: Invalid value of option
>   modules->sql_type: expected map, got string instead

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
sql_type: "mysql"
```

try:

```
sql_type: mysql
```